# 可愛くないのはやだけど妙に気合い入れたと­思われるのも

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 可愛くないのはやだけど妙に気合い入れたと­思われるのも...

Context: A girl goes to buy pajamas, but she's not sure which one she should buy (she's shown having trouble picking up). Then she says that sentence.

I'm not sure about why there's ない after 可愛く. From what I can understand, the girl is saying that she doesn't want to buy cute pajamas because it would be strange for her to do so (I guess it's implied she doesn't like to look cute). Anyway, I'm not sure if I really get what she means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可愛くないのはやだけど means "I don't want to buy uncute pajamas".

やだ would follow the phrase 妙に気合い入れたと­思われるのも.

I translated 妙に気合い入れた­と思われる as "Others think that I strangely fire myself up (by wearing too cute pajamas)." or "Others think that I strangely fire myself up (by buying too cute pajamas)."
気合い入れる means "to fire oneself up, to give it one's all, to get psyched". So buying(wearing) too cute clothes mean "to fire oneself up" in this context.

For example, when she come a party in too dressed up clothes, some people may say　"彼女、気合入れすぎ!".

So this sentence means "Though I don't want to buy uncute pajamas, too cute ones either."

Comment: Thank you! So is there some kind of implication about what others could think? I guess the sentence means "I don't want to buy  pajamas that aren't cute, but I don't want to buy ones that are  too cute either" (since other people could think "These pajamas are too cute" , I guess?

Comment: Your guess is almost right. This 思われる means "I am though", that is "Others think".  And I changed  my answer a little. It is  "since other people could think I strangely fire myself up by wearing(buying) too cute pajamas".

Answer (score 2):

> 可愛くないのは**や**だけど

The や is short for いや (嫌), "don't like/want" or "hate".

"I don't want uncute ones but" （≂ 「可愛くないのはイヤだけど」）

<sub>breakdown:

可愛くない -- "not cute"

の -- 準体助詞/phrasal particle "the one"

は -- topical/contrasitve particle

や ＜ いや -- "hate, don't like"

だ -- copula

けど -- conjunction "but"</sub>

---

> 妙に気合い入れたと­思われるのも...

「いや（だ）」 or something similar is left unsaid at the end (because it can be implied without being explicitly uttered).

*lit.* "(I don't want) the ones that might be thought of as strangely pumped up, either..."
→ "I don't want the ones that would make others think that I am oddly/unusually/too pumped up, either..."
(≂ 「妙に気合を入れたと思われるのもイヤだ」)

<sub>breakdown:

妙に -- "strangely/oddly" or maybe "unusually" (or "(a bit) too much"?)

気合い入れた -- "to be pumped up, to be fired up"

と -- quotative particle

­思われる -- passive of 思う "to be thought"

の -- "the one"

も -- binding particle "either"</sub>

Comment: Thank you!  I'm a bit confused about the "pumped up" though. Why does she feel that others would think that she's pumped up?

Comment: If she chose too cute or colorful pajamas, others might think that she's too excited/serious/high-spirited... she's saying she doesn't want to buy pajamas that are too colorful, though she doesn't want uncute ones, because she doesn't want to look too excited/high-spirited... I didn't know how to translate 気合を入れる in this context.. I think it's like "too fired up, too exited, or too high-spirited (about some special event?)"

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, was the word "妙に" omitted on purpose in your translation?

Comment: @Romi It literally says "strangely/oddly/curiously" or maybe "unusually/unexpectedly"... and I thought it's like "too (much)" ... ≂ 気合を入れすぎる ("too excited", or "pour too much effort?").

Answer (score -1):

I'm also a little confused. Reading this, my understanding of it is something along the lines of "Even though it's not cute, I find it strange that I'm getting psyched."

I could be misunderstanding, but it looks like she wants it to be cute?

> 「可愛くないのはやだけど」

As in, "This isn't cute, but..."

Edit: I guess reading everyone else's reply, I didn't take into consideration the 思われる, which I know is the passive tense form of 思う, where the action is being done to you by another person. So, I incorrectly treated it as "思う" and incorporated it as "I find" in my original sentence.

I think the other users covered it better, but when I do add that 思われる、it changes to "Even though it's not cute, others would find that I'm getting strangely psyched."